# React native iOS App run time error : dyld: Symbol not found:

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, xcode12

I am getting following error from one of the pod frameworks while running the app (Build is a success).

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN5swift34swift50override_conformsToProtocolEPKNS_14TargetMetadataINS_9InProcessEEEPKNS_24TargetProtocolDescriptorIS1_EEPFPKNS_18TargetWitnessTableIS1_EES4_S8_E.

**Referenced from:** X framework

**Expected in:** frameworks/DeviceKit.framework/DeviceKit

Xcode 12.4

React native 0.63

cocoapods: 1.10.1